# JPA duplicate entity creation issue

Tags: jpa, ejb-3.0

I implemented a ejb3 stateless session bean to import set of recipients to the database . I committed each recipient record, with @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW) in a public method

```
 @Stateless
 @Local(ImportRecipientManagerLocal.class)
 @SecurityDomain("recipient")

 public class ImportRecipientManagerSLB implements ImportRecipientManagerLocal {

 @EJB
 private ImportRecipientManagerLocal anotherRecipientManager;

 @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
 @TransactionTimeout(30 * 60)
 @Override
 public RecipientImportStatus saveRecipient(Recipient recipient) throws 
 ImportRecipientFailedException  {
       // saves the reicpient
  }


 public  RecipientsImportStatus createRecipients(List<Recipient> recipientList) {

 // while recipient exist in list
    anotherRecipientManager.saveRecipient(recipient);  
 // end while

}
```

The problem is when customer has  , submitted 2 same files (contents are same) simultaneously  , it had created duplicate recipients. I think this is because the two session bean processors are executed in parallel. but what bothers me is , since the end of saveRecipient , the transaction is committed , the data should be visible to the other transaction. Isn't it?

I can't understand how it is happening, Appreciate if someone could assist me on this.

Comment: REQUIRES_NEW creates a new transaction and suspends the one that was active. The new transaction is not part of the context of the existing one. The other transaction will only be resumed when the new transaction ends (commit or rollback). Is that the behavior that you expect?

Comment: Hi helderdarocha, there are two parallel transactions running in this case , because as I mention the records are imported simultaneously. What I think is the transaction in the second process, should see the changes done in the  transaction of the first prcoess , because the transaction is committed in end of the method saveRecipient

Answer (score 0):

as you said if the transactions are running parallel simultaneously, it had created duplicate recipients however if we use FlushMode.COMMIT it means it always synchronize with database before committing it and that's why the 2nd process record insert fails with constrain violation. So it is always recommended to flush before committing.